# NSLog the address of NSArray

Tags: cocoa, nsarray, nslog

When I type this on console

```
print myArray       .... myArray is a NSArray
```

I see this

```
(NSArray *) $0 = 0x00006100002494e0 @"6 objects"
```

How do I build a NSLog line to print this address `0x00006100002494e0` to console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"%p", myArray);
```

Would be suitable.

You can see a list of format specifiers in the Apple documentation over [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `%p` format specifier, which prints an address or pointer variable:

```
NSLog(@"Address of my array: %p", myArray);
```